# How to draw from the inside of the light geometry in deferred shading

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to implement a deferred shader with OpenGL and GLSL and I'm having trouble with the light geometry. These are the steps I'm taking:

```
Bind multitarget framebuffer
Render color, position, normal and depth
Unbind framebuffer
Enable blend
Disable depth testing
Render every light
Enable depth testing
Disable blend
Render to screen
```

But since I'm only rendering the front face, when I'm inside a light it disappears completely, rendering the back face does not work, since I would get double the light power (And when inside, half [or the normal amount]).

How can I render the same light value from inside and outside the light geometry?

Comment: "*Accumulate with glAccum*" ... why is that there?

Comment: @NicolBolas I... have no idea... it wasn't working before without that, I guess I wasn't using blending before. I'll remove from the question.

Comment: you probably should include stencil test to exclude areas from the light volume where no geometry is rendered.

Comment: @fscan how do I do that?

Comment: set stencil to 1 when rendering geometry, blit depth/stencil to light buffer, render lightvolumes only where stencil is 1.

Comment: Nowhere-01's is right, you can do depth testing with GEQUAL, to render only back faces behind geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i remember correctly, in my deferred renderer i just render **only** the backfaces of the light volume. <strike>The drawback is you cannot depth test, you will only know if a light is behind a geometry after the light calculation is done and discard the pixel.</strike>
As another answer explained, you can do depth testing. Test for greater or equal to see if the backface is behind or on a geometry, therefore intersects with the surface of the geometry.

Alternatively you could check if you are inside the light volume when rendering and switch front faces accordingly.

Comment: Rendering only the backface worked, but after a number of lights if I'm inside the light geometry my fps drop to half, is this related?

Comment: try the stencil trick, if your inside the light geometry you are rendering the whole screen otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

well in my case, i do it like that:

```
Bind gbuffer framebuffer
Render color, position, normal
Unbind framebuffer

Enable blend
Enable depth testing

glDepthMask(0);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);   //to render only backfaces
glDepthFunc(GL_GEQUAL); //to test if light fragment is "behind geometry", or it shouldn't affect it
Bind light framebuffer
Blit depth from gbuffer to light framebuffer //so you can depth-test light volumes against geometry
Render every light
```